# Group .vbs files separately rather than all at once

Tags: vbscript, windows-scripting

I know I can split my VBScript into separate files and then include them all with one .wsf file. Something like this:

MyScript.wsf

```xml
<job id="MyJob">
   <script language="VBScript" src="File1.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File2.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File3.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File4.vbs" />
</job>
```

`C:\> cscript MyScript.wsf`

But, is there a way that I can include a .wsf file, or some other grouping of .vbs files? This way I can treat a set of files as a unit, rather than having to list all of the files out individually.

Library1.wsf

```xml
<job id="Library1">
   <script language="VBScript" src="File1.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File2.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File3.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File4.vbs" />
</job>
```

Library2.wsf

```xml
<job id="Library2">
   <script language="VBScript" src="File5.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File6.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File7.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File8.vbs" />
</job>
```

MyScript.wsf

```xml
<job id="MyJob">
   <script language="???" src="Library1.wsf" />
   <script language="???" src="Library2.wsf" />
</job>
```

`C:\> cscript MyScript.wsf`

Comment: Why would you try to use a WScript Script File as a way of storing libraries of VBScript? The whole point of a WSF is to group scripts together for a specific task, not as re-usable libraries. You're trying to add structure where there isn't any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this that's a bit ugly but works is to concatenate partial files together using the `type` command. `cscript.exe` doesn't support piping though, so you have to use a temp file. Something like the following:

Start.txt

```xml
<job id="MyJob">
```

Library1.txt

```xml
   <script language="VBScript" src="File1.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File2.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File3.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File4.vbs" />
```

Library2.txt

```xml
   <script language="VBScript" src="File5.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File6.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File7.vbs" />
   <script language="VBScript" src="File8.vbs" />
```

End.txt

```xml
</job>
```

`C:\> type Start.txt Library1.txt Library2.txt End.txt > temp.wsf & cscript temp.wsf & del temp.wsf`

Or I guess you could even kind of think of it like compiling:

build.bat

```vb
@echo off
type Start.txt Library1.txt Library2.txt End.txt > MyScript.wsf
```

Comment: This is a hack at best, but closest so far.